# The Quintessential Quintuplets (aka 五等分の花嫁) : Is 届くんです (it reaches) a mondegreen that should be 五等分です (It's divided into five equal parts)?

Tags: music, japanese-language, culture, theme-song, the-quintessential-quintuplets

In [animesonglyrics](https://www.animesonglyrics.com/gotoubun-no-hanayome/gotoubun-no-kimochi), you can see in the season 1 opening (Gotoubun no Kimochi) for the anime adaptation of [The Quintessential Quintuplets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Quintessential_Quintuplets)

1. the Romaji: Go-tōbundesu, demo (...) --> the Kanji of which I think is: 五等分です, でも (...)
2. the English: It reaches, but (...)
3. the Kanji: 届くんです, でも (...) --> the Romaji of which I think is: Todokundesu, demo (...)

source: https://www.animesonglyrics.com/gotoubun-no-hanayome/gotoubun-no-kimochi

[image]

It seems the English and the Kanji match, but they are both different from the romaji.

Now, in a live performance [here](https://youtu.be/_g7geUDY1ts?t=69), you can see the actress/singer Inori Minase holds up 5 fingers when singing this line, sooo...

[image]

1. I guess the Romaji is correct, while the English and Kanji are wrong?
2. But it's a mondegreen, i.e. it's understandable to mishear Go-tōbun (五等分) as 届く (Todoku)?

Comment: Cross-posted from Japanese.SE: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/93612/5464

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The original lyric doesn't mention *todoku* at all.**

Here is a part of [the lyric listed on Joysound](https://www.joysound.com/web/search/song/727383) (one of, if not, the most popular karaoke services in Japan),

> (一花.二乃.三玖)
> 大嫌いから
> (四葉.五月)
> (大嫌いから)
>
> (一花.二乃.三玖)
> 大好きへと
> (四葉.五月)
> (大好きへと)
>
> (二乃) 変わる心に
> (全員)
> ついていけないよ
>
> (一花.二乃.三玖)
> どんなことも
> (四葉.五月)
> (どんなことも)
>
> (一花.二乃.三玖)
> あなたさえ
> (四葉.五月)
> (あなたさえ)
>
> **(五月) 五等分です**
> (一花) でも私
> (二乃) 私 (三玖) 私
>
> (四葉) 私
> (五月) 私は
> (全員) あなたが好きよ

[The Wiki Fandom](https://5hanayome.fandom.com/wiki/Gotoubun_no_Kimochi#Romaji_) also got it right.

Comment: Thanks Aki Tanaka♦! Any idea if it's a mondegreen or something? I'm obviously just a beginner in japanese, sooo...

Comment: @BCLC it's unlikely a mondegreen if no other sites (especially Japanese lyric sites) agree about using the expression 届く there. Looks like it's just a mistake by the contributors of that site.

Comment: ok thanks, but putting aside your good a posteriori argument. from you know (Gasai) the words themselves 'todokun' might be, a priori, heard from 'gotoubun' ? what do you think?

Comment: @BCLC sorry, I don't know who or what Gasai is, but there's no relation between *todokun* (which the base word is *todoku*) and *gotoubun*.

Comment: right thanks then  Aki Tanaka♦! (Gasai is, you know [Gasai], Yuno Gasai)